# How can i tell when a Directshow.net conversion is done?

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

right now I have a Directshow.net graph that takes in a video file and encodes it to a file, however it just continues to run

```
int x = program.Run()
```

in DirectShow.net and i want the program to close when the full conversion is done instead of me having to guess.

how can i tell if its done encoding programatically?

Comment: If you have a mediaEvent variable you can check against the WaitForCompletion function to see if the code is done running. if the result of the waitforcompletion ( gh in this case) is not 0, it is running, if it is equal to 0, then its done.


    const int E_Abort = unchecked((int)0x80004004);
    EventCode evCode;
    int gh = mediaEvent.WaitForCompletion(1000, out evCode);
    DsROTEntry rot = new DsROTEntry(filter);
    while (gh == E_Abort)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        gh = this.mediaEvent.WaitForCompletion(1000, out evCode);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a mediaEvent variable you can check against the WaitForCompletion function to see if the code is done running. if the result of the waitforcompletion ( gh in this case) is not 0, it is running, if it is equal to 0, then its done.

```
const int E_Abort = unchecked((int)0x80004004); 
EventCode evCode; 
int gh = mediaEvent.WaitForCompletion(1000, out evCode); 
DsROTEntry rot = new DsROTEntry(filter); 
while (gh == E_Abort) 
{ System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); 
gh = this.mediaEvent.WaitForCompletion(1000, out evCode); }
```