# SmartTee filter and saving to file

Tags: c#, video, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

How can I render video stream from webcam to file if I use smart tee filter?
So I add SmartTee filter and get something like that:

```
Capture filter
        |
    SmartTee filter
    |           |
capture     preview
    |           |
Mux filter  GrabFilter
    |           |
FileWriter  VideoRenderer
```

So that's connetion capture filter and smart tee:

```
// Get capture filter
srcFilter = FindCaptureDevice();

// Add Capture filter to our graph.
graph.AddFilter(srcFilter, "Video Capture");

//Add smartTee filter to graph
smartTeeFilter = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();
graph.AddFilter(smartTeeFilter, "Smart Tee");

IPin outPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, srcFilter);
IPin inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, smartTeeFilter);
graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);
```

That's connection with grabber and rendering (just in case):

```
sampGrabber = new SampleGrabber() as ISampleGrabber;
baseGrabFilter = sampGrabber as IBaseFilter;
graph.AddFilter(baseGrabFilter, "Grabber");

IPin sourcePin, grabPin;
sourcePin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, smartTeeFilter);
grabPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, baseGrabFilter);           
graph.Connect(sourcePin, grabPin);

graph.Render(GetPin(PinDirection.Output, baseGrabFilter));
```

And that's all I have in saving file part:

```
IBaseFilter mux;
IFileSinkFilter sink;

capture.SetOutputFileName(
    MediaSubType.Avi,      // Specifies AVI for the target file.
    path,                  // File name.
    out mux,               // Receives a pointer to the mux.
    out sink);             // (Optional) Receives a pointer to the file sink.

sink.SetFileName(path, null);

IPin outPin = DsFindPin.ByDirection(smartTeeFilter, PinDirection.Output, 1);
IPin inPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, mux);
graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

control.Run();
```

It's no thrown exceptions. Just creating file with size 64Kb. What's wrong with my saving to file code?

Added.
I check out CapWMV example and in there saving is like this:

```
IFileSinkFilter sink = null;
IBaseFilter fileWriterFilter = null;
capture = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2) new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
capture.SetFiltergraph(graph);
int hr = capture.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, path, out fileWriterFilter, out sink);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

hr = capture.RenderStream(null, null, smartTeeFilter, null, fileWriterFilter);
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

hr = control.Run();
DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
```

And again I get 64 Kb file and nothing else. Where's my mistake?

Comment: HALP ME GUYZ, I'm stuck. It's just saving to file. Without smart tee it's two lines of code. It can't be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology on the top is about right.

Your code however does not match it: you connect multiplexer input and then you `Run`. No code exists or shown to connect multiplexer output, which is mandatory.

Next thing is that your actual topology might differ from expected because of filters provided automatically with Intelligent Connect, you  need to review this as well by either enumerating filters or [publishing to ROT and viewing with external tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312084/how-can-i-tell-when-a-directshow-net-conversion-is-done).

If you had a chance to look at *real* topology, you would perhaps grasp the problem immediately:

```
IPin sourcePin, grabPin;
sourcePin = GetPin(PinDirection.Output, smartTeeFilter);
grabPin = GetPin(PinDirection.Input, baseGrabFilter);           
graph.Connect(sourcePin, grabPin);
```

You are connecting first grabbed output pin to Sample Grabber and preview video renderer. However, [index zero output pin is Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The capture pin is output pin 0, and the preview pin is output pin 1.

So you are writing preview (timeless) media samples to a file, it is not going to work, so you need to connect tee output pins properly - so that tee's capture output is connected to mux/writer leg.

Comment: Oh, right, there's no connection between mux and file writer. And now I got that I have no idea how to do it. So it leads me to dumb question: how does connect mux and file writer?

Comment: Get the pins and do `graph.Connect` on them, just as you connect other pairs.

Comment: Yep, but should I use `sink` as `IBaseFiler` or something else?

Comment: There is nothing new compared to what you are already doing on the presented code. You have filters, they have pins, pins are connected. So you find pins of interest and connect them.

Comment: I got it. But I can't get which filter should be used at end. If I use `sink` for connection with `mux` I get "No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection". What filter should I use and how to create it?

Comment: Have a look at DirectShow.NET's `CapWMV` sample, and `SetupGraph` there. It sets up file writing correctly and is a good guide for you about how things are done (incluuding putting graph on ROT - it is also there).

Comment: Basically with this CapWMV example I'm doing the same thing I did before using SmartTee. And it worked. But with SmartTee have no luck.

Comment: All right, your not wanting to check back the topology making everyone guess. See my answer update above.

Comment: I'm just stupid and not quite understand how to use this ROT and so on. So I'm sorry. And thank you!